# nextjs import query function in pages

Tags: mysql, node.js, next.js

I am just starting to learn Next.js and I have a question about importing server side rendering code in pages.

So, I have a function which accepts query and executes that query. And I also have a function which utilizes this query function and processes and returns data.

```
// query function
import mysql from 'serverless-mysql';

const db = mysql({
    config: {
        host: host,
        port: port,
        database: database,
        user: user,
        password: password
    }
})

export default async function selectQuery({ query, values }) {
    try{
        const results = await db.query(query, values);
        await db.end();
        return results;
    } catch(error) {
        return { error };
    }
}
```

```
// utilizing function
import selectQuery from './db';

export async function getAllId() {
    try {
        const result = await selectQuery({ query, values })
        
        return result.map((row) => {
            return {
                params: {
                    id: row.ID
                }
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return [{
            params: {
                id: ''
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

The problem is I can import query function in pages (getStaticProps and getStaticPaths) just fine and get the result, but I get an error when I try to import the second function that utilizes this query function.

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'

```
// pages/analysis/[id]/compare.js
import selectQuery from '../../../lib/db'; // from first code. gives no error
import { getAllId } from '../../../lib/fn'; // from second code. gives error

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await getAllId();
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

I can't even get to getStaticProps and getStaticPaths because of this import error. I get that in Next.js, a page can have server side rendering and any server side code must be in getStaticProps or getStaticPaths (or getServerSideProps). But, I was wondering why I am getting import error when importing a function that utilizes query function.

Shouldn't I get the same error when importing query function as well?

My Next.JS version is LTS, serverless-mysql version is ^1.5.4 and node version is 16.13.2.

Comment: In which file did you try to import `net` (or the package that requires it)?

Comment: @code I am trying to import in both pages, but specifically in pages/analysis/[id]/compare.js, it gives module not found error. In /pages/analysis/[id].js, it does not give any error.

Comment: The `net` module is a built-in node package and can't be run in the browser. You'll only be able to use it in files that are only executed on the server, like your code in the `/api` directory.

Comment: @code Yes, I understand that built-in node package cannot be run in the browser, but in pages/analysis/[id]/compare.js, if I import query function (it uses serverless-mysql), it gives no error, but if I import a function that utilizes this query function, it gives error. Shouldn't importing query function also give error since it also uses built-in node package?